# Error : Expected identifier or '(' after usage of old Objective C library in Swift project through bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have quite low experience with Objective C as I started learning iOS development using Swift and I need to use a older ObjC library.

My netsdk.h library (file has over 50k lines)

```
#ifndef DHNETSDK_H
#define DHNETSDK_H

#if (defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64))

   ... 
#else    //non-windows

    #define CLIENT_NET_API extern "C"
    #define CALL_METHOD 
    #define CALLBACK
    ...
```

Basically after reading some problems related to this one I think there is problem with `extern "C"` on the next line

```
...
#define CLIENT_NET_API extern "C"
...
```

Due to this  I am getting errors on many lines that use CLIENT_NET_API like

```
expected identifier or '('
Expanded from macro 'CLIENT_NET_API'
```

My first try was to wrap `#define CLIENT_NET_API extern "C"`
into

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#define CLIENT_NET_API 

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

but then I am getting error `"C does not support default arguments"` on all lines using CLIENT_NET_API
for example these

```
CLIENT_NET_API BOOL CALL_METHOD CLIENT_StartBackUpCase(LLONG lLoginID, const NET_IN_START_CASE_BACK_UP* pstInParam, NET_OUT_START_CASE_BACK_UP *pstOutParam, int nWaitTime = NET_INTERFACE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

CLIENT_NET_API BOOL CALL_METHOD CLIENT_StopBackUpCase(LLONG lLoginID, const NET_IN_STOP_CASE_BACK_UP* pstInParam, NET_OUT_STOP_CASE_BACK_UP *pstOutParam, int nWaitTime = NET_INTERFACE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
```

I think it should be wrapped in some other way but I couldn't find a example with `#define` and `extern` keywords on the same line

Comment: post more code, please

Comment: @Vyacheslav added more code

Comment: Hi, i am using the same library and gettig the same error without finding a solution... did you get to run your code?

Comment: @muca No I believe I couldn’t find a solution (have no objc skills whatsoever anyway)

Answer (score 1):

In this case:

## define CLIENT_NET_API extern "C"

Says, let `CLIENT_NET_API` be `extern "C"`

So, in your case you just define as `empty existed preprocessor variable`

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#define CLIENT_NET_API 

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: define as empty existed preprocessor variable ? I don't quite get it ....code you provided is the same as what I tried and I already mentioned it in my post (not working / got more errors)..
Can you please give me exact solution ?

Answer (score -1):

I used file.mm to #import "netsdk.h" instead of file.m.
Problem solved